# Is there a directive for when you have two select list next to each other and you can select an item from one and put into another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for an angular directive or widget - I don't know whether using the widget expression proper or not - for implementing a surface where the user can get roles. On left hand the rights listed belong to the user listed in a multiple select field. On left hand side the rights available for the user are listed also in a multiple select list.

The attached picture is about TFS column options, but this is what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately, I don't know what is the name of a widget like this and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it is not necessary.

I appreciate for any help in advance!

[image]

Comment: You could try scouring through this stuff http://ngmodules.org/ `ui-bootstrap` comes to mind that has general widgets, BUT this seems like a great time to write a directive to me. This is so simple that reinventing the wheel seems like an overkill statement. If you can't find it, make it and publish it for everyone else! (I've made this exact thing before.)

Comment: This the plan "B". :) Thanks for answering!